# How to get two decimal digits while casting from long to float in c programming

Tags: c

How to get two decimal digits while casting from long to float in c program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long l = 3.5340304343;   

    printf("%.2f", (float) l);

    return 0;
}
```

Current Output: **3.00**

Expected Output: **3.53**

Comment: Integers only store whole numbers; assigning `3.534…` saves `3` in `l` — how do you expect to get the fraction back?  You need to multiply by 100 and round; assign; divide by 100.0 to stand a chance.  Don't forget to add a newline to the end of the output format.  And converting to `float` only to have the argument promotion rules convert back to `double` seems pointless; use `l / 100.0` or thereabouts.

Comment: Does the compiler **warn** you? *'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'long', possible loss of data.*

Comment: @WeatherVane No, it didn't warned anything.  Command I'm using is, `gcc -o bin/test test.c` (Codeblocks, Windows Platform)

Comment: What is it you are thinking would happen here? A `long` is an integer type. When 3.5340304343` is assigned to `l`, it has to be converted to an integer. Then `l` has only an integer value. When you convert an integer value to a `float`, there is only the integer value to be converted. The fractional part is gone, and the conversion cannot bring it back. Did you think something different would happen? What, and how?

Comment: In that case you should increase the warning level. With gcc (I think) that is -Wall. With MSVC the warning was given by default.

Comment: `gcc -o test ../test.c -Wall`

Adding '-Wall', Producing some meaningful statements,

`../test.c:7:12: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]
     printf("%.2f", l);`
            ^

`long` => `double` working fine. Basically I'm a Python developer, so I missed out this basic thing. Thanks all.

Comment: Same thing would happen in pyton.  Try: `int(3.5340304343)`

Answer (score 0):

`int`, `long`, `long long` type variable only store the integer value. If you assign a floating point number to them it will only assign the number left to the decimal point. As it doesn't store anything after decimal point so you can't able to retrieve any digit after decimal point after assigning a number in `int`, `long`, `long long` type of variable. You should have use `float` or `double` to work with floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

When storing a value in an `int` or a `long` the value stored as a whole number and the data after the decimal point is removed. And there is no way to retrieve it

You should use a `float` or a `double`.